# What's the best cold call pitch for a freelancing software engineer?

Tags: attracting-clients, communication, marketing, sales

When I cold call a hiring manager for the first time, what exactly is the best thing for me to say after they answer?

I've been a contract software engineer for 25 years.  Times are always changing.

I used to say:
"Hello, I'm , a software engineering contractor, and I'm calling to offer my services."

But lately this is often interpreted to mean that I'm a job shop offering the service of providing contractors.

I'm mainly looking in the Silicon Valley area.  Hiring managers are 95% of the time friendly.

It's 2017.  What should I say?

specifically:
Should I say I'm a "freelance software engineer" or a "contract software engineer"?   Is "freelance" a thing these days?

Answer (score 3):

I try to keep things quick, to the point, and professional - saves everyone time. I've never written down a script since each project/company can vary a lot, but something along the lines of:

> "Hi, my name is {name}, I'm an experienced software freelancer, and I see your company does/needs {thing}, which I have {experience/interest} in. I just wanted to call to see if discussing {potential project} might be mutually beneficial. Do you have a couple minutes to talk?"

I feel like this approach generally works for the person on the other end, because you:

1. Act like a person and treat them the same, not like a sales rep hunting a lead-generation bonus

   - Acknowledge (briefly) that you don't have an existing relationship
   - Don't demand a lot of time, or that they concede to a follow up be ending with "when can I call you back?"
   - They've probably read the same books on pushy sales techniques that you have, and no one likes feeling manipulated by being on the receiving end of a pushy approach
2. Show you've made an effort to understand them specifically

   - Mention that you've done your homework/research on the company and its (and by extension, the callee's) needs
   - State (or at least imply) that you believe you can help them
   - You are reaching out to them specifically, not just running through a cold-call list
   - State that you have experience with the tools needed to solve their problems
3. Establish the sort of relationship you want to have

   - You are someone who takes initiative
   - You want to focus on how you can help them, but aren't going to work for free
   - You respect their time by being brief, and their authority in their job by not being pushy
   - Imply that you want a partnership as an outside resource, and are not interested in being a direct hire

Answer (score 0):

> "Hi, I'm a software engineer, who works on a contract basis, and I'm calling to offer my services."

You've got "contractor" in a poor location. A "contractor" **is** someone that hires others to do the work. i.e. "General Contractor", "Talent Contractor", "Plumbing Contractor". So, it stands to reason people hearing "Software Engineer Contractor" assume you hire software engineers.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm changing my stuff to "Freelance Software Engineer".  How's that sound.

Comment: Better :)  ( random extra text so comment submits)

Answer (score -1):

{TheirName}

You and I haven't spoken before but my name is {YourName}, i understand that you're the {TheirRole}, is that correct?

{Silence until they respond}

Great, the reason for my call today is that I've been following {TheirCompany} for a while and it looks like you're a bit short staffed on engineers, is that right?

{Silence until they respond}

Cool, I've worked for the past {NumYears} at companies like {Company1}, {Company2} and {Company3} as a {WhateverYourRole}.

When is a good time for you to set aside 15-20 minutes next week to talk through if my background is a good fit?"

{Stop talking}

Comment: This sounds exactly like a headhunter script - I'd hang up by the 2nd pause.